# Liquibase / Long running DB scripts

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, liquibase

Using Spring Boot and managing database changes by Liquibase all changes are executed on application start. This is totally fine for fast running changes.

Some changes, e.g. adding DB index, can run for a while. If running application on K8s it happens that liveness/readyness checks trigger an application restart. In this case Liquibase causes an end-less loop.

Is there a pattern how to manage long running scripts with Liquibase? Any examples?
One approach might be splitting the the changes in two groups:

- Execute before application start.
- Or execute while application is already up and running.

Answer (score 1):

Defer long running script after application start. Expose DB upgrade invocation via private REST API or similar.

Your code and dev practice have to support n-1 version of DB schema. Eg: hide the feature that needs new column behind feature flag until schema upgrade fully rolled out.

Comment: Thanks! Trigger via REST API sounds good.

I was thinking about using different context definitionns on changelog.xml - will keep overview of all DB changes on one place.

Is there any sample "how to trigger update by code"? Best nicely integreated in Spring Book, e.g. using same config props. And without copying too many Spring Boot classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [init container](https://www.liquibase.com/blog/using-liquibase-in-kubernetes) to init your database before application startup.